# Finding average of last 3 not null values from sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I need to find the average of the last 3 values from a column in my SQLite database which contains null and not null values . However I need to find the average of only the not null values. ie. if the column contains 3,0,4,0,5,0,10 i need the average to be (10+5+4)/3.
Can anybody help me with the query I could use. Iam a rookie to SQLite.
Any help would be appreciated
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume you have a column `to_order` which contains the order you want to retrieve the rows in and `col` which contains your numbers:

```
select avg(col) from tbl where col is not null order by to_order desc limit 3;
```

If you have further questions, leave a comment.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, would you kindly click the green check to accept it? Many thanks!

Comment: There are quite a few [accessors for Cursor objects](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html). Perhaps one of those might be of assistance?

Comment: I have done this -  predictionCursor = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT AVG(_mileage) FROM fuel_table WHERE _mileage IS NOT null ORDER BY _id DESC LIMIT 5", null);
   if(predictionCursor!=null && predictionCursor.getCount()>0)
   {
    predictionCursor.moveToLast();
    findAvgMileage = predictionCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_MILEAGE);
    pd.setpredictionMileage(findAvgMileage);
   }
Is this right way to do it?

Comment: Does it work? If so, it's right... I'm not an Android programmer, more of a data analyst

Comment: Not at all. Glad you got it sorted.